# How to execute cmake env bash command line succesfully?

Tags: bash, cmake

I got to a build script, that contains a call equivalent to `cmake -E env bash script.sh`, which keeps failing on my system, as the exit code returned is always 1.

So I wanted to debug this on the command line:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.26.3
```

First, let's try a simple bash command, and check its exit status:

```
$ bash -c 'echo aaaa' ; echo $?
aaaa
0
```

Ok, so exit status was 0 here; now let's try call this via `-E env bash`:

```
$ cmake -E env bash -c 'echo aaaa' ; echo $?
1
```

Ok, this should have been trivial - but something is wrong, as the command exits with status 1.

So - how can I correctly run a `cmake -E env bash -c` command on the (bash) command line, so it completes successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... apparently I need an absolute path for the call to `bash` there, so the following seems to work:

```
$ cmake -E env `which bash` -c 'echo aaaa' ; echo $?
aaaa
0
```

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 (and you may also need to read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)